# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type List<> and List<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

```
 li = warehousetocustomlist.Where(x => x.Created_By == (long)HttpContext.Current.Session["Slno"]).ToList() && warehousetocustomlist.Where(x=>x.Type==3).ToList();
```

Here I'm checking two conditions which is present in the same list but it showing error as:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type List<> and List<>.

Comment: Where will be written once only before ToList .Where(x => x.Created_By == (long)HttpContext.Current.Session["Slno"] &&
           x.Type==3)

Answer (score 1):

You have ToList in wrong place:

```
li = warehousetocustomlist
    .Where(x => x.Created_By == (long)HttpContext.Current.Session["Slno"] &&
           x.Type==3)
    .ToList();
```